# What Will Happen Under This Situation with Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have synced some folders from Ubuntu 12.10

Now i installed 13.04 and manually deleted some ( many actually) files from the synced folders( i did a manual backup in an external HDD and then organised the data b4 re-copying it to 13.04)

now when i sign in to Ubuntu one, will the deleted files be downloaded again or will the files on the web be deleted rather?

i want the 2nd situation to take place actually!

m not signing in to ubuntu one untill i get the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a test on this. I used

```
touch testfile.txt
```

and it uploaded the file to my personal cloud. I synced my phone and the file was there.
I then deleted the file from the Ubuntu One folder on the computer and did not get another message saying that the file was being downloaded again, and when I re-synced my phone, the file was gone.

Based on that little experiment, I would say if you deleted them from the folder itself, they wont try and download themselves again.

Comment: oookay! thanx a lot! ;) ill sign in and c now! thanx a lot! :D

Comment: The phone apps don't do sync. Whether the files will download again or not depends on whether the metadata was also kept after the upgrade. If it was not, it will likely download the file again, rather than delete it on the server. If the metadata was also preserved during the upgrade, then the file should get deleted on the server (and any other synchronized computers).

Comment: well, i just had a look now, and NO! the 2nd situation did not tak place! :( @dobey i dint get what u xactly mean by metadata was kept, but it started downloading everything! so i had to manually go to the website and delete everything that i dint want to get downloaded! :(  this really is a problem! there should be options given on such situations!

Comment: OK. I don't know what you did exactly. But this isn't a forum to discuss it. The way I described, is how the code is designed and written. If it started downloading again, then you probably only copied over some files, and didn't copy the metadata, so the missing files were re-downloaded.